# Buggy scroll with jQuery Parallax

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, parallax

On the page: *[LINK REMOVED]* I'm using the https://github.com/richardshepherd/Parallax-Scrolling/ plugin. Is there a reason scrolling is jagged and jumpy? How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Possibly because of the over 15MB of images that the browser has to struggle with

Comment: @MrOBrian [Epica Wines](http://www.epicawines.com/) seems to do this alright, is there something wrong with the javascript that may be causing this problem?

Comment: It actually scrolls ok for me; a little jumpy, but not bad. However, I have a very powerful development machine. It's possible there is some javascript that is slowing it down too. I also notice you have two different version of jQuery loaded on that page

Comment: @MrOBrian Thanks for the tip, it seems like the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once duplicate jQuery files and large image files removed the problem was solved (credit to @MrOBrian).